# TYPO3 Fluid: Selectbox option with leading zero

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to render a selectbox where you can select hour and minute:

```
<f:form.select property="minute" options="{0: '00', 5: '05', 15: 15, 30: 30, 45: 45}" />
```

This worked in earlier versions of TYPO3 (version 6.2), but in version 8.7 (and 10.4), the output is:

```
<select name="...">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

Isn't it possible to output `<option value="0">00</option>`?

Answer (score 1):

I can only respond with "it does" :-) Try fluid here

https://fluidtypo3.org/library/try-fluid-now.html

Comment: The result is as expected in the online demo and in TYPO3 7.6 and 6.2, but not in TYPO3 8.7.8.

Comment: And not in TYPO3 10.4 LTS